# Rate of packet arrival

Tags: probability-distributions, network

Channel has bit error probability p. Number of bits in packet is Poisson distributed with mean lambda. How do I calculate the rate of successful packet arrival?
This is what I have done so far: Assume n bits in packets. k out of n bits are in error and arrive with prob p and rest n-k bits arrive with prob 1-p. How does the Poisson distribution come into the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of bits in packet is poisson distributed with mean $\lambda$.

The number of bit errors ( X)  in the packet = $\lambda p$

The rate of successful packet arrival will be P(X=0) = $\frac{(\lambda p)^0 \exp{(-\lambda p)}}{0!} = \exp(-\lambda p)$

Note:There is a rule of thumb stating that the Poisson distribution is a good approximation of the binomial distribution if n is at least 20 and p is smaller than or equal to 0.05, and an excellent approximation if n ≥ 100 and np ≤ 10.

Comment: Thank you. Now if packets arrive at Poisson rate mu, how would you calculate the rate of successful packet arrival?

Comment: It has to do with cascade of poisson processes as the problem definition does not fit merge or splitting property of Poisson.  I am researching into it to see if I can answer is correctly.  Thanks

Comment: A cascade Poisson Process is not a poisson process.  Attached is an article that describes with an application.http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~fessler/course/516/l/c6-noise.pdf  Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome.